# Por qué este programa de tkinter no almacena el valor del Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

Lo que el programa debe hacer es atrapar el valor del Entry e imprimirlo en consola cuando se presione el botón, pero no lo hace.

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()
raiz.title("ejemplo")

miframe=Frame(raiz)
miframe.pack()

textoGuardado=""

texto_imprimir=Entry(miframe).pack()
textoGuardado+=(texto_imprimir)

def imprime_en_consola(t):
    print(t)

Button(miframe, text="imprime", command=lambda:imprime_en_consola(textoGuardad)).pack()

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Creo que tienes una gran confusión cuando almacenas un `Entry` en una variable, guardas un objeto, no el texto de este. Para conseguir el contenido de un `Entry`, puedes usar un [`StringVar`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) o el método [`get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas cosas mal en tu código. Algunas simples errores de sintaxis, otras errores de concepto, y otras finalmente errores de lógica en el flujo de ejecución. Así que vamos por partes.

### Errores de sintaxis

Este es obvio, tienes una variable global `textoGuardado` que dentro de la función lambda has llamado `textoGuardad`. Este error ni siquiera llega a producirse porque antes tienes otro de concepto.

### Errores de concepto

En Tkinter (y en la mayoría de *toolkits* para desarrollo de interfaces gráficas de usuario), se van creando componentes (o *widgets*) y se van empaquetando en un contenedor que dicta la forma en que se organizan visualmente.

La creación de componentes la haces mediante llamadas a las clases que crean cada componente. Así, en tu código tienes dos:

- `Entry()` que crea un componente de entrada de texto
- `Button()` que crea un botón y lo asocia a una acción

Cuando llamas a los constructores de la clase obtienes una referencia al componente en cuestión, que te permitirá después interactuar con ese componente. Por ejemplo el velor retornado por `Entry()` tiene un método llamado `.get()` que te permite obtener el texto que el usuario haya escrito en esa entrada.

Uno de tus problemas es que no recoges el valor retornado por estos constructores, pues tienes algo como:

```
variable = Entry().pack()
```

Es decir, el valor retornado por `Entry()` es un objeto que no llegas a almacenar, porque inmediatamente haces la operación `.pack()` sobre ese objeto. Es el valor retornado por `pack()` el que guardas en `variable`. Por desgracia `pack()` retorna `None` siempre, por lo que no tiene sentido guardarlo, y lo que es peor, ya no tienes forma de acceder al componente `Entry` que acabas de crear.

> Nota al margen, tu código parece suponer que el valor retornado por `.pack()` sería el texto que el usuario tecleó. Esto no solo no es así, sino que no puede ser así, pues el usuario aún no ha tecleado nada ya que el componente acaba de ser creado.

Lo que tienes que hacer por tanto es tener una variable separada para esa componente, que después empaquetarás. Es decir:

```
entry = Entry()  # La creamos
entry.pack()     # la empaquetamos
```

Gracias a esto conservamos en la variable `entry` una referencia al componente, de modo que más adelante, cuando lo necesitemos, podremos invocar `entry.get()` para obtener el texto que el usuario haya escrito.

Lo mismo cabría decir respecto al botón. De nuevo haces `Button(...).pack()`, creando un botón sin guardar una referencia a él y empaqutándolo inmediatamente después. En este caso el problema no es grave ya que realmente no necesitamos acceder más al elemento `Button`, pero si quisieras desde el código hacer cosas con el botón (por ejemplo, inhabilitarlo, habilitarlo de nuevo, cambiarle el color, etc..) sí necesitarías una referencia al mismo, por lo que tendrías que primero crearlo (guardando la referencia) y luego empaquetarlo, como hicimos antes con la `Entry()`.

### Errores lógicos en el flujo de ejecución

Finalmente viene lo más difícil de entender. ¿En qué orden ocurren las acciones en tu programa?

En principio ocurren en el orden en que las escribes, que sería:

1. Se crea la ventana principal y en ella un `Frame()`
2. Se crea la `Entry() y se empaqueta.
3. Se crea una función (que no se ejecuta aún)
4. Se crea un botón y se asocia con una función (pero tampoco se ejecuta esa función aún)
5. Se inicia el bucle `mainloop()`

En ese punto la interfaz de usuario se presentará en pantalla. El usuario puede escribir cosas en la Entry (tkinter se ocupa de recibir ese texto y mostrarlo dentro de la Entry, así como de manejar las teclas de edición tales como borrar, mover cursor, etc)

En algún momento el usuario pulsa el botón. En ese momento Tkinter detecta el evento y como consecuencia ejecuta la función asociada con el botón. *Es en este momento cuando podremos acceder a `entry.get()`* para leer lo que el usuario haya escrito. Hasta ese momento no tiene sentido ya que el usuario pudo no haber escrito nada aún.

Por tanto es desde la función asociada al botón desde la cual tenemos que leer el texto e imprimirlo.

### Solución final

Una solución que simplemente imprime cuando se pulse el botón lo que el usuario ha tecleado sería así:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()
raiz.title("ejemplo")

miframe=Frame(raiz)
miframe.pack()

entry = Entry(miframe)
entry.pack()

def imprime_en_consola():
    texto = entry.get()
    print(texto)

Button(miframe, text="imprime", command=imprime_en_consola).pack()

raiz.mainloop()
```

Como ves no hace falta `lambda`. El comando asociado al botón puede ser directamente el nombre de una función (que será llamada siempre sin parámetros). La lambda puede ser necesaria si necesitaras pasar algún parámetro a la función, pero no es el caso. El texto a imrprimir no lo recibe como parámetro sino que lo saca de la `entry`.

En tu código tenías una variable global llamada `textoGuardado` cuyo cometido no tengo claro. No sé si es un error más debido a que no comprendías bien como funcionaba todo, o es que realmente querías tener una variable que, cada vez que el usuario pulse el botón, vaya creciendo. Es decir, el usuario teclea "Hola" y pulsa el botón, y la variable contendrá "Hola" (y se verá por pantalla). Después borra "Hola" y escribe "Adios" y pulsa de nuevo el botón, y la variable pasará a contener "HolaAdios" (y se muestra por pantalla). Esa variable iría concatenando todas las entradas que el usuario vaya haciendo.

La idea de ir concatenando la saco de que tú tenías una línea que decía `textoGuardado+=(texto_imprimir)`. Repito que no sé si realmente pretendías esto, pero si ese fuera el caso, el siguiente programa haría lo que buscas:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()
raiz.title("ejemplo")

miframe=Frame(raiz)
miframe.pack()

entry = Entry(miframe)
entry.pack()

textoGuardado = ""

def imprime_en_consola():
    global textoGuardado

    texto = entry.get()
    textoGuardado += texto
    print(textoGuardado)

Button(miframe, text="imprime", command=imprime_en_consola).pack()

raiz.mainloop()
```